# JavaScript : How create proportionality rule function with array parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, arraylist

I want to create an Array from another by applying the proportionality rule.

**For example:**

```
Array1 = [15,550,76,3,400,230]
```

- I take the maximum value from `Array1` which is equal in my array `550`
- Now, with a function, I want to create a second array `Array2` with a value equal to 10 which corresponds to `550` in the first array, like `Array2 = [?,10,?,?,?,?]`
- I want to apply the proportionality rule function to determine the other values of `Array2` to get `Array2=[0.27,10,1.38,0.05,7.27,4.6]`

Any help please how can I create the function with array param?

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What is the problem you have? Writing a function? Passing an array as argument? Finding a maximum value in an array? Creating a second array? ...etc... etc. This is too broad. You should focus on a specific issue you have in tackling this challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const array1 = [15,550,76,3,400,230]

function proportionalityRule(array){
  const maxValue = Math.max(...array)
  return array.map(element => (element/maxValue) * 10)
 }

proportionalityRule(array1)
// (6) [0.2727272727272727, 10, 1.3818181818181818, 0.05454545454545455, 7.272727272727273, 4.181818181818182]
```